# Assistance with recursions

Tags: python, recursion

This is what I am suppose to be figuring out. I really want to understand or if there is a good resource that would help that would be great too not just an answer.

Consider the sequence `{x(n)}` defined by `x(1) = 1` and `x(n+1) = 2*x(n) + 1` for n ≥ 1. Write a recursive function `recSeq(N)` which computes and returns x(N) . Use this function to determine x(100) and print the output.

This are the final that I have been able to get a number to print although it is not the correct number.

```
if N ==0:
    return 1
elif N >= 1:
    return 3
else:
    return recSeq((2*N) +1)
```

If I do the below it just keeps running all replying with errors

```
if N ==0:
    return 1
elif N == 1:
    return 3
else:
    return recSeq((2*N) +1)
```

Comment: Hint: x(n+1) = 2*x(n) + 1 is equivalent to x(n) = 2*x(n-1) + 1

Answer (score 0):

If you're asked for x(n), what you need to do is evaluate x(n-1), in order to calculate 2*x(n-1)+1. And to evaluate x(n-1) you need to evaluate x(n-2) etc. The only exception to this is x(1) = 1.

It's also a good idea to check `n >=0`, to stop the program getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
def recSeq(n):
    if n <=0:
        raise ValueError('n must be >= 1')
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return(2*recSeq(n-1)+1)
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution :

```
def recSeq(n): return 1 if  n==1 else 2*recSeq(n-1)+1
```

recursion is easy : a basic case, a general case.